# Sum of a range of cells that may contain + sign

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a google sheet table with the cells A1, B1 and C1 containing
either an integer, e.g., `12` or an expression `<integer> + <integer>`, e.g.,  `12 + 1` or `12+1`.

I want to compute the sum of the cells in `D1`. Situation

```
|A1|  B1 | C1|
--------------
|1 | 1+1 | 3 |
```

should result in 6. Simply saying `D1 = SUM(A1:C1)` does not work:
it ignores the cell `B1`.

I have found two partial solutions that I cannot combine:

- `SUM(SPLIT(B1;"+"))` results in 2
- if I had `A2: 1`, `B2: 4` and `C2: 9`, then `ArrayFormula(SUM(SQRT(A2:C2)))` results in 6 (sum of square roots of these cells).

(e.g., `ArrayFormula(SUM(SUM(SPLIT(A1:C1;"+"))))` does not work properly)

How can I solve this problem? Two-step solution i) compute `SUM(SPLIT(<cell>;"+"))` in a new cell, and ii) compute the sum, is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=SUM(SPLIT(JOIN("+",A1:C1),"+"))`

In this solution you just need to join them first.

BTW this formula works too:

`=SUM(SPLIT(JOIN("+",A1:C1),"+:)"))`

Comment: You need to use `;` or to use comma `,` and to change `file → regiolal settings` to `US`